# How can I access to library " plot_utils " in python?

Tags: python, anaconda

I need this library "plot_utils" for analysis and plotting but I can't find it in the web. this library is  related to Brian2 (a library in python) for spiking neural network.
I installed brian2 through anaconda. when I want to import plot_utils and using in my code I receive error :

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plot_utils'

Could you please help me?

Comment: You must have gotten there using any reference, what's that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give more info about where did you stumble upon that name, eg some copied code etc.

With the only reference you've given (ie. brian2) this seems related.

https://brian2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/frompapers.Stimberg_et_al_2018.plot_utils.html

Maybe just copy that code into a file named 'plot_utils.py' and keep it at the path your code is searching for it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to install the module in your work environment using "pip install plot_utils" then you can import the library using "import plot_utils".

This link will help you: [https://libraries.io/pypi/plot-utils[this](https://libraries.io/pypi/plot-utils%5Bthis) is the official documentation from plot_utils]